# Oracle merge statement within procedure fails to recognize variable in using clause

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, upsert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UPSERT into table with dynamic table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762376/upsert-into-table-with-dynamic-table-name)

The following procedure is declared as so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  
PROCEDURE STUFF(tableToQuery VARCHAR2) AS  
BEGIN  
    MERGE INTO myTable m  
    USING (select * from tableToQuery)  t  
    ON (m.id = t.id)  
...  --other stuff
END STUFF;
```

I receive an ORA-00903 error that states the table name is invalid.  My question is how do I get the value that resides within `tableToQuery` to equate to a valid table name in the select statement?  Assume that I do not know the table name ahead of time.

**UPDATE**

The function compiles now, however I currently receive the unknown keyword error at the end of my function.

Comment: "unknown keyword" indicates a syntax error.  Alas we are not telepathic.  So we cannot spot syntax errors in code you haven't posted.  If you're using the dynamic SQL solution you will need to post the SQL statement which your procedure generates.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use dynamic SQL: ie construct your SQL statement in a string and then pass that string to Oracle to execute using the `execute immediate` statement.

Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  
PROCEDURE STUFF(tableToQuery IN VARCHAR2) AS
  s varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  s := 'MERGE INTO myTable m'
    || ' USING (select * from ' || tableToQuery || ')  t'
    || ' ON (m.id = t.id)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE s;
  --other stuff
END STUFF;
```

should do the trick for you.

NB don't pass unverified data from end users (especially ones on the web) in the parameter `tableToQuery` as then you will have a SQL injection vulnerability!

Comment: Seems to do the trick, will keep you posted

Comment: I always double-quote Oracle identifiers in dynamic SQL,
    ... from "' || tableToQuery || '" ...

That way any valid tablename in Oracle (even using mixed case or spaces etc) will also work in my dynamic code.

Comment: Hmm I am now getting the unknown keyword error at the end of my function.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you output the generated statement?